# Настройка OpenVPN. Centos 7(server). Windows 7(Client)

Tags: centos, клиент-сервер, windows-7, openvpn

Пробовал настроить OpenVPN с помощью tutorial разных сайтов на сервере и на клиенте. Не получилось везде в конфиге клиента есть какой-то `tls-auth .../ta.key` который нигде на сервере не могу найти . Подскажите как создать ta.key или сайт где все написано четко.

Answer (score 2):

в [документации написано](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Hardening#Useof--tls-auth), как сгенерировать ключ:

```
$ openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
```

файл `ta.key` будет создан в текущем каталоге. переместите его в нужный каталог. или генерируйте сразу там, где надо.

Comment: Это на сервере?

Comment: @СамБарсегян, это там, где у вас в конфигурационном файле упомянут файл `ta.key`, а его нет.